# Attempting to run Haskell File on GHC error

Tags: haskell

When attempting to load Haskell file test.hs into terminal. I get this response:

```
<interactive>:5:1: error: Variable not in scope: test :: b0 -> c

<interactive>:5:6: error: Variable not in scope: hs :: a -> b0
```

This is the code from test.hs:

```
double x = x + x

quadruple x = double (double x)
```

How do I get the file to load in terminal?

openai says look for documentation or may need to import module?

Comment: Can you also share the GHC command you're running?

Answer (score 3):

That's what happens if you type `test.hs` at the GHCi prompt. You meant to type `:l test.hs` instead.

Comment: <no location info>: error: can't find file: test.hs
Failed, no modules loaded.
That is the response I get when I type in what you suggested

Comment: @JonathanOsman Is your `test.hs` file in the same directory that you're in when you ran `ghci`? If you specify an absolute path to it instead, does that work any better?

Comment: Yes, it has to do with the directory I believe. Nobody else mentioned this yet except you. I moved it to the directory it was searching and received this
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.